# Display the result of SQL query (count (*) and group by) in Chart

Tags: vb.net

I want to display the total Ticket number per Department in a Column Chart and of course it will be based in Month.
Sad to say, I can't get the result that I want.

Sample Table

Table Name: TblTickets

```
Ticket_ID   Dept        Date_Time

1111        ACCT        07/01/2019 10:30AM

1112        PLNG        07/02/2019 10:30AM

1113        LAB         07/02/2019 10:30AM

1114        ACCT        07/03/2019 10:30AM

1115        ACCT        07/04/2019 10:30AM

1116        LAB         07/04/2019 10:30AM

1117        HR          07/04/2019 10:30AM
```

Here is my code.

```
Public Sub GDept()

        con.Open()
        SQLString = String.Empty
        SQLString = "SELECT Dept, COUNT (*) FROM TblTickets GROUP BY Dept ORDER BY Dept ASC"
        SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(SQLString, con)

        Dim GDataReader As SqlDataReader = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader
        ChartDept.DataBindTable(GDataReader, "Dept")
        GDataReader.Close()

        con.Close()

End Sub
```

I'm getting this error

> "Data points insertion error. only 1 y values can be set for this data
>   series"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.
Add an alias for your total Tickets, so the Databinding can reference your aggregate column [Count(*) as -alias-].

```
Dim lSqlCmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT Dept, COUNT(*) as total_tickets FROM TblTickets GROUP BY Dept ORDER BY Dept ASC", lCon)
```